# Как изменить стандартный SSH порт?

Tags: iptables, ssh, порт

В файле **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**, я изменил строчку **Port 22** на **Port 68**.
Теперь не по **SSH** не по **SFTP** не коннектиться. Подозреваю, что сам порт не открыт где то в iptables.

Посоветуйте, как мне сделать возможным использование нестандартного порта?

Comment: Не правильно. Нужно, сначала - прописывать ДВА порта. Релоад SSHd. Попробовать на второй. Если нет коннекта, то проверить правило в iptable-ipfw, если нет - добавить по аналогии с 22 портом. Попробовать снова. Если коннектится, то 22 можно убирать. Да, по идее, при смене портов сервер не будет рвать текущее соединение, но а вдруг проблемы со связью... Поэтому сначала настроили новое - потом отключили старое.

Answer (score 2):

Рестартануть sshd случаем не забыл и при конекте указать этот измененный порт ну ssh -p 68

Answer (score 2):

1.изменяется в настройках sshd_config Port

2.если политика ЗАКРЫТО ВСЕ, что не ОТКРЫТО, то добавляется в правила файрвола.

3.рестарт sshd

4.проверка удаленно через telnet yourip 68